# Python: how to format a long very complex string to subprocess.run function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, subprocess

I need to run a couple of complex bash commands from Python. One of them is:

```
top -n1 -b | awk -vtime="$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)" 'NR==7{printf("Time\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$5,$6,$9,$10,$11,$NF)}' > ~/logs/perfmon.log
```

This command prints a header to a file, using the `top` command, and formats the string using `awk`.

The second command finds the process named `process_name` and continuously records its performance with the `top` command to the created file. The command is NOT awaited in Python.

The problem is that the command itself contains both double quotes `"` and apostrophe `'`, as well as the escape characters `\t` and `\n`. And it's a long string.

I've tried to define the command string as `f-string` and put double `\` before the escape characters, I've tried to use the `r-string`, but with no success.
Either the header line is printed without tabs between words, or the command is misinterpreted by the `awk` command.

I attach my function below. Both commands need some help :)

I'd appreciate you checking the solution before posting here.

```
def execute_performance_monitoring(sample_frequency: int = default_top_frequency) -> None:
today = datetime.today()
date = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')

process_name = "find_and_log_me"

logs_dir = Path(logs_path)
full_file_name = logs_dir / f'{process_name}_{date}.log'

print_header_command = (
    'top -n1 -b'
    ' | awk -vtime="$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)" \'NR==7{{printf("Time %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\\n",$1,$5,$6,$9,$10,$11,$NF)}}\''
    f' > {full_file_name}'
)

print_perfmon_command = (
    f'top -b -o +%CPU -d {sample_frequency}'
    '| awk -vtime="$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%T)" \'NR>8{{printf("%s %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\\n"'
    ',\'time,$1,$5,$6,$9,$10,$11,$NF)}}\''
    f' | grep --line-buffered {process_name} >> {full_file_name} &'
)

subprocess.run(print_header_command)
subprocess.run(
    print_perfmon_command,
    shell=True,
    stdin=None,
    stdout=None,
    stderr=None,
    close_fds=True,
)
```

Comment: Does anybody accept the challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries and days without a success, I've moved the commands to a bash script that takes the relevant parameters, and Python script does the validation job, and calls the bash script with parameters.